# Deleting rows for a given variable with missing values

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataset with many missing values in `Gender`.

The path I took, which is probably not the best is first creating a variable with the genders.

```
Gender = dataset['Gender'].isin(['M', 'F'])
```

And now merging this series with the dataframe.

```
dataset1 = pd.DataFrame.merge(dataset, Gender)
```

This of course, it´s not working.

How can I solve this? Ty

Comment: I think you simply need this: dataset.dropna(subset=['Gender'], inplace=True)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you mean by?

```
dataset.loc[dataset['Gender'].isin(['M', 'F'])]
```